# SQLite: how to update 2 tables at once with single computed math

Tags: sql, sqlite, sql-update

Here is the query that doesn't compile just to show how it should look like.

```
SELECT * FROM Buying AS BB, Selling AS SS 
WHERE (
   UPDATE Buying, Selling
   SET Buying.boughtPending = Buying.boughtPending + willBuyAmount,
   SET Selling.soldPending = Selling.soldPending + willBuyAmount
      WHERE EXISTS (
           SELECT
                  CASE
                       WHEN( B.amount - B.bought ) >( S.amount - S.sold ) THEN( 1 + ABS( RANDOM(  ) %( S.amount - S.sold )  )  ) 
                       ELSE( 1 + ABS( RANDOM(  ) %( B.amount - B.bought )  )  ) 
                  END AS willBuyAmount
             FROM Buying AS B, 
                  Selling AS S
           ON B.itemId = S.itemId 
           AND
           B.aborted = 0 
           AND
           S.aborted = 0 
           AND
           B.boughtPending = 0 
           AND
           S.soldPending = 0 
           AND
           B.price >= S.price 
           AND
           S.sold < S.amount 
           AND
           B.bought < B.amount
           LIMIT 1 
      )
  ) AND BB.boughtPending > 0 AND SS.soldPending > 0 LIMIT 100;
```

Comment: It is not possible to update two tables in the same statement; use transactions. Show how you would implement your algorithm with a bunch of small statements, then maybe we can help you.

Comment: I don't know how to break it down into smaller queries I need that `UPDATE` to get looped until the `SELECT` inside it returns nothing... I can't run the `SELECT` inside there without `LIMIT 1` because the results will not be right.